# Add custom field to contact form Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, custom, forms, contact-form

I'm using magento 2 and I would like to add a custom field to the contact form , how I would be able to do that ?

Comment: Here is good explanation regarding how to add Custom Field in Contact form https://belvg.com/blog/how-to-add-custom-fields-into-a-contact-form-in-magento-2.html . Please go though it.

Answer (score 43):

First, open the **`form.phtml`** file located in your theme.

**/magento_root/app/design/frontend/VENDER_NAME/YOUR_THEME/Magento_Contact/templates/form.phtml**, then add subject field to this contact form:

```
<div class="field subject required">
    <label class="label" for="subject"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Subject') ?></span></label>
    <div class="control">
        <input name="subject" id="subject" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Subject') ?>" value="" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Add the above field in the form.

As far as Magento is concerned, it doesn't care what fields we add to this form. It is written in such a way that it accepts all of the field posted for processing and send that out to the transactional e-mail form that you create. Now, go to **MARKETING > Communication > Email Templates** in the Magento Admin section. Click "**Add New Template**" and from the "**Template**" dropdown box select "**Contact Form**" then "**Load Template**". Under template content you will see:

```
{{trans "Name: %name" name=$data.name}}
{{trans "Email: %email" email=$data.email}}
{{trans "Phone Number: %telephone" telephone=$data.telephone}}
{{trans "Comment: %comment" comment=$data.comment}}
```

Add your new field before **Name: {{trans "Name: %name" name=$data.name}}** so that now it should looks like this:

```
{{trans "Subject: %subject" subject=$data.subject}}
{{trans "Name: %name" name=$data.name}}
{{trans "Email: %email" email=$data.email}}
{{trans "Phone Number: %telephone" telephone=$data.telephone}}
{{trans "Comment: %comment" comment=$data.comment}}
```

Enter a new name under "**Template Name**" to save your new Template and click on "**Save Template**". Now we need to tell Magento to use this new template for the Contact form. Go to **STORES -> Settings -> Configuration -> General -> Contacts** and select "**Contacts**". Under "**Email Options**", select your new template under the "Email Options" -> "Email Template" dropdown box. Click on "**Save Config**".

Comment: This is correct, instead of creating the template for the email in te database, I would override the template in my theme (/magento_root/app/design/frontend/VENDER_NAME/YOUR_THEME/Magento_Contact/email/submittted_form.html). It's just personal taste ;)

Comment: @StijnDuynslaeger-Echron Hi, the file name `submittted_form.html` has a extra `t`, the correct template path is `/magento_root/app/design/frontend/VENDER_NAME/YOUR_THEME/Magento_Contact/email/submitted_form.html`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add extra field in contact form and send it with email,Go to vendor/magento/magento_contact/view/templates/frontend/form.phtml

```
<div class="field subject">
<label class="label" for="subject"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Subject')) ?></span></label>
<div class="control">
<input name="subject" id="subject" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Subject')) ?>" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper(\Magento\Contact\Helper\Data::class)->getPostValue('subject')) ?>"class="input-text" type="text" />
</div>
</div>
```

Go to admin,Marketing->Email Templates->Click on "Add new Template"->Select Contact form->Click on "Load Template"

```
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}
<table class="message-details">
<tr>
<td><strong>{{trans "Name"}}</strong></td>
<td>{{var data.name}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td><strong>{{trans "Subject"}}</strong></td>
<td>{{var data.subject}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td><strong>{{trans "Email"}}</strong></td>
<td>{{var data.email}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>{{trans "Phone"}}</strong></td>
<td>{{var data.telephone}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
<p><strong>{{trans "Message"}}</strong></p>
<p>{{var data.comment}}</p>
{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

> Save Your Template,
> Go to Stores->Configuration->General->Contacts->In "Email Options" select your template->Save Config