# How to override contact us post action using plugin Magento 2

Tags: magento2, overrides, controllers, plugin

I want to override contact us post action using plugin as i have custom field in my contact form.
I have created di.xml file,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <type name="Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post">
        <plugin name="custom_contact_action" type="Pos\Contact\Plugin\Post"/>
    </type> 
</config>
```

This is my Plugin file,

```
<?php

namespace Pos\Contact\Plugin;
class Post 
    {

 public function aroundExecute(\Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post $subject)
    {

        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        if (!$post) {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        }
        $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
        try {
            $postObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
            $postObject->setData($post);

            $error = false;

            if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['name']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }
            if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['comment']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }
            if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['email']), 'EmailAddress')) {
                $error = true;
            }
            if (\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['hideit']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }
            if ($error) {
                throw new \Exception();
            }

            $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
            $transport = $this->_transportBuilder
                ->setTemplateIdentifier($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, $storeScope))
                ->setTemplateOptions(
                    [
                        'area' => \Magento\Backend\App\Area\FrontNameResolver::AREA_CODE,
                        'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
                    ]
                )
                ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $postObject])
                ->setFrom($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER, $storeScope))
                ->addTo($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT, $storeScope))
                ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
                ->getTransport();

            $transport->sendMessage();
            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(
                __('Thanks for contacting us with your comments and questions. We\'ll respond to you very soon.')
            );
            $this->getDataPersistor()->clear('contact_us');
            $this->_redirect('contact/index');
            return;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
            $this->messageManager->addError(
                __('We can\'t process your request right now. Sorry, that\'s all we know.')
            );
            $this->getDataPersistor()->set('contact_us', $post);
            $this->_redirect('contact/index');
            return;
        }
    }


        
    }
```

When i submit the form then it shows me error ,

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
> Pos\Contact\Plugin\Post::getRequest() in
> /var/www/html/pospaper/app/code/Pos/Contact/Plugin/Post.php:10 Stack
> trace: #0
> /var/www/html/pospaper/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135):
> Pos\Contact\Plugin\Post->aroundExecute(Object(Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post\Interceptor),
> Object(Closure)) #1
> /var/www/html/pospaper/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153):
> Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}()
>
> ## 2 /var/www/html/pospaper/generated/code/Magento/Contact/Controller/Index/Post/Interceptor.php(26):
>
> Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post\Interceptor->___callPlugins('execute',
> Array, NULL) #3
> /var/www/html/pospaper/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(107):
> Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post\Interceptor->execute() #4
> /var/www/html/pospaper/vendor/magento/module-contact/Controller/Index.php(67):
> Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\Ap
> in /var/www/html/pospaper/app/code/Pos/Contact/Plugin/Post.php on line
> 10

Please help me!!!! Thanks in advanced!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following code:

```
namespace Pos\Contact\Plugin;


class Post
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory
     */
    protected $resultRedirectFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface
     */
    protected $messageManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface
     */
    protected $inlineTranslation;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
     */
    protected $transportBuilder;

    /**
     * Core store config
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $scopeConfig;

    /**
     * Post constructor.
     * 
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory $resultRedirectFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory $resultRedirectFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
        $this->resultRedirectFactory = $resultRedirectFactory;
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
        $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post $subject
     * @return $this|void
     */
    public function aroundExecute(
        \Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post $subject
    ) {

        $post = $subject->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        if (!$post) {
            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('*/*/');
        }
        $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
        try {
            $postObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
            $postObject->setData($post);

            $error = false;

            if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['name']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }
            if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['comment']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }
            if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['email']), 'EmailAddress')) {
                $error = true;
            }
            if (\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['hideit']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }
            if ($error) {
                throw new \Exception();
            }

            $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
            $transport = $this->transportBuilder
                ->setTemplateIdentifier($this->scopeConfig->getValue(\Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, $storeScope))
                ->setTemplateOptions(
                    [
                        'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
                        'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
                    ]
                )
                ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $postObject])
                ->setFrom($this->scopeConfig->getValue(\Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER, $storeScope))
                ->addTo($this->scopeConfig->getValue(\Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT, $storeScope))
                ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
                ->getTransport();

            $transport->sendMessage();
            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(
                __('Thanks for contacting us with your comments and questions. We\'ll respond to you very soon.')
            );
            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('contact/index');
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
            $this->messageManager->addError(
                __('We can\'t process your request right now. Sorry, that\'s all we know.')
            );
            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('contact/index');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this
create `di.xml` file in your custom module

```
/magento2/app/code/Contact/Custom/etc/di.xml
```

add below code in `di.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="\Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post" type="Contact\Custom\Controller\Index\ExtendIndex" />
</config>
```

create `ExtendIndex.php` file

```
/magento2/app/code/Contact/Controller/Controller/Index/ExtendIndex.php

<?php
     namespace Contact\Custom\Controller\Index;
class ExtendIndex extends \Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post
{
    /**
     * Index action
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function execute($coreRoute = null)
    {


        $this->messageManager->addSuccess('Message from new controller.');
        return parent::execute($coreRoute);
    }
}
```

Comment: This was not working for me!! i have tried this solution.

Comment: please remove var/generation folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access directly `$this->getRequest()` in plugin, You should access like below method

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request

    ) {
        $this->_request = $request;

    }
```

Replace `$post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue()`; by `$post = $this->_request->getPostValue();`

Answer (score 1):

To add Custom field in email template please Follow Below Link

[Add custom field to contact form Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115344/add-custom-field-to-contact-form-magento-2#answer-115395)

[Overriding Block, Model, Controller in Magento2](https://webkul.com/blog/overriding-rewriting-classes-magento2/)

> app/code/Overriding/Magento2/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

       <preference for="Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post" type="Overriding\Magento2\Controller\Index\Post" />

</config>
```

> app/code/Overriding/Magento2/Controller/Index/Post.php

```
public function execute()
    {
        if (!$this->isPostRequest()) {
            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('*/*/');
        }
        try {
            $this->sendEmail($this->validatedParams());
            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(
                __('Thanks for contacting us with your comments and questions. We\'ll respond to you very soon.')
            );
            $this->dataPersistor->clear('contact_us');
        } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
            $this->dataPersistor->set('contact_us', $this->getRequest()->getParams());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->critical($e);
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(
                __('An error occurred while processing your form. Please try again later.')
            );
            $this->dataPersistor->set('contact_us', $this->getRequest()->getParams());
        }
        return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('contact-us');
    }
```