# Add Subject to the Contact form Email Template in magento 2

Tags: magento2, email, contact-form

I have customised the Email template of Contact Us email with adding some new fields into it.
However, i want to know where is the option to add Default subject to the email. When my user submits contact us form, i receive email with blank subject.
Let me know how can i add subject?

Answer (score 1):

You can write email subject to in your email .html file

```
<!--@subject {{trans "Your Subject Write Here "}}  @-->
```

You can pass subject dynamic by follow below example

```
<!--@subject {{trans "Welcome to %store_name" store_name=$store.getFrontendName()}} @-->
```

Comment: Have you tried this ? Let me know if its helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add subject in you email template file by add below the line on top of the file content:

```
<!--@subject Subject Text  @-->
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Did not get you. Please ellaborate.

Comment: @Nafisa Just add the above-given line in your template file first line and replace your custom text with "Subject text" to set the default subject.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to easy way Please check follow setps

First open form.phtml file located in your theme

`/magento_root/app/design/frontend/VENDER_NAME/YOUR_THEME/Magento_Contact/templates/form.phtml`, then add subject field to this contact form:

```
<div class="field subject required">
    <label class="label" for="subject"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Subject') ?></span></label>
    <div class="control">
        <input name="subject" id="subject" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Subject') ?>" value="" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Add the above field in the form.

As far as Magento is concerned, it doesn't care what fields we add to this form. It is written in such a way that it accepts all of the field posted for processing and send that out to the transactional e-mail form that you create. Now, go to `MARKETING > Communication > Email Templates` in the Magento Admin section. Click "Add New Template" and from the "Template" dropdown box select "Contact Form" then "Load Template". Under template content you will see:

```
{{trans "Name: %name" name=$data.name}}
{{trans "Email: %email" email=$data.email}}
{{trans "Phone Number: %telephone" telephone=$data.telephone}}
{{trans "Comment: %comment" comment=$data.comment}}
```

Add your new field before Name: {{trans "Name: %name" name=$data.name}} so that now it should looks like this:

```
{{trans "Subject: %subject" subject=$data.subject}}
{{trans "Name: %name" name=$data.name}}
{{trans "Email: %email" email=$data.email}}
{{trans "Phone Number: %telephone" telephone=$data.telephone}}
{{trans "Comment: %comment" comment=$data.comment}}
```

And save template. Now we need to tell Magento to use this new template for the Contact form. Go to `STORES > Settings > Configuration > General > Contacts and select "Contacts"`. Under "Email Options", select your new template under the "Email Options" > "Email Template" dropdown box. Click on Save Button.

And check this more information :-

[Add custom field to contact form Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115344/add-custom-field-to-contact-form-magento-2)

You can write email subject to in your `email .html` file

```
<!--@subject {{trans "Welcome to %store_name" store_name=$store.getFrontendName()}} @-->
```

Thanks...

Comment: I did not want to add subject as a text field. i am talking about the subject which we receive in email. Subject of the email

Comment: try this :- {{var this.getSubject()}} and refer this :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35123779/how-to-add-subject-in-tranctional-email-template-for-magento-2-version

Comment: Hello @Nafisa check my update answer hope help...